# Entity Framework маппинг.

Tags: entity-framework

Всем привет. Нужна помощь при маппинге. Для того чтобы не усложнять пример, приведу некий упрощенный случай. Есть иерархия классов, например:

```
class Person
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Student : Person
{
    public string NikName { get; set; }
}
```

В БД есть таблица, предположим, что ее название People. Как отразить данные из этой таблицы на сущность Student.

Answer (score 2):

@sp7 Вы используете Code First или "классический" подход с edmx файлом и генерацией классов?

- Если edmx то там есть визульный редактор и в нем есть раздел "Table Mapping" - думаю это то что вам нужно. Сказать по правде, я пробовал сделать что-то сложное на заре EF так вот тогда возможности этого инструмента были **очень** ограниченны... не знаю как сейчас, но он тут :
  [image]
- Если Code First то дела обстоят намного лучше. Как сделать маппинг можно узнать  [в этой статье](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping) а если нужно за 10 минут узнать про Code First то вот тут [классное обучающее видео](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx)

Надеюсь это вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и статьи. Мне нужно было настроить через Code First, так-то разобрался как это сделать. Видать что-то с базой сначало было, никак "контакт" не шел. Потом пересоздал БД и все заработало!

Comment: @sp7 без проблем, если что пишите, попробую помочь :-) Удачи!

Comment: Сейчас пробую подобную иерархию классов, как в примере выше, отобразить на две таблицы связанные "Один к Одному", т.е. есть одна базовая таблица, которая хранит общие данные сущности  и есть связанная с ней таблица, которая хранит дополнительные данные. 

Сделал. Все вроде работает, но не знаю насколько верно я все сделал. Похожих примеров в инете не нашел.